# How to get the Date Of Birth given number of years months and days of a person in java

Tags: java

Given year, month and days of a person, need to get Date of Birth - 
Example - 19 years 1 moth and 2 days 
16-Sept-2010 (have calculated it manually, may not be accurate)

Comment: What have you tried apart from calculating the result manually? Could you show us your attempt, please? That means code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LocalDateTime.now().minusYears(years).minusMonths(months).minusDays(days)
```

Comment: Or is it `LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(days).minusMonths(months).minusYears(years)`? May not be the same result. --- If I gave my age in year, months, and days, I would have gotten that by adding those numbers in that sequence to by birth date, so to correctly reverse that, you have to subtract the numbers in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can use the modern API for dates and times `java.time` and especially the class `LocalDate`. It has methods to add or subtract units of time, such as days, months and years.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Imagine someone being 19 years, 1 months and 2 days old today...");
    LocalDate birthday = getBirthdayFromAge(19, 1, 2);
    System.out.println("Then this person was born on "
                        + birthday.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
}

public static LocalDate getBirthdayFromAge(int years, int months, int days) {
    return LocalDate.now()
            .minusDays(days)
            .minusMonths(months)
            .minusYears(years);
}
```

This outputs

```
Imagine someone being 19 years, 1 months and 2 days old today...
Then this person was born on 2000-09-15
```

Comment: Or is it `LocalDate.now().minusDays(days).minusMonths(months).minusYears(years)`? May not be the same result. --- If I gave my age in year, months, and days, I would have gotten that by adding those numbers in that sequence to by birth date, so to correctly reverse that, you have to subtract the numbers in reverse order.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't subtract anything from a `LocalDateTime` but from a `LocalDate` and I got the same result with reversed subtractions. Have you taken the same values? I'm interested…

Comment: Sorry, copied comment from another answer which used `LocalDateTime`. Updated my comment. If you change number of days to 20, and since today is the 17th, it will cross to previous month, so the result depends on the number of days in the previous month, so the result is different depending on whether you subtract days before months, or months before days. E.g. `2019-10-17` (today) minus `19y 1m 20d` is `2000-08-28` with `.minusYears(years).minusMonths(months).minusDays(days)`, but it is `2000-08-27` with `.minusDays(days).minusMonths(months).minusYears(years)`.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, totally right, thanks. I have edited the answer...

Answer (score 2):

I would go with [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`java.time.Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class. Calling `minus` methods might not be optimal as it will create new object for every method invocation (classes like `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` are immutable) :

```
Period period = Period.of(19, 1, 2); //period of 19 years, 1 month, 2 days
LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.now().minus(period); // compute the birthday

String formattedDate = birthday.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMMM-YYYY", Locale.UK));
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

The output is :

```
15-September-2000
```

Comment: Note that `localDate.minus(Period)` is actually broken. If birth date is `2000-08-27`, and today is `2019-10-17`, then person is `19 year, 1 month, and 20 days` old. With `birthDate = LocalDate.of(2000, 8, 27)` and `age = Period.of(19, 1, 20)`, that works out right, i.e. `birthDate.plus(age)` is `2019-10-17`, but note that `birthDate.plus(age).minus(age)` is *not* the birth date, but `2000-08-28`. --- `minus(age)` is not the reverse of `plus(age)`, it is actually the same as `plus(age.negated())`.

Comment: @Andreas you are right. This is somewhat interesting. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945704/adding-and-subtracting-period-from-localdate-doesnt-produce-the-same-date) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471207/localdate-minus-a-period-get-wrong-result) threads which explain why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

You should to transform year to Timestamp,month to Timestamp, day to Timestamp.
Diff this with current timestamp and you will get birth date Timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Here is quick fix for you. Please check following code.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Birthdate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Birthdate calUsage = new Birthdate();
        calUsage.subtractTime();
    }

    private void subtractTime() {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

        String pattern = "yyyy-MMMM-dd";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println("Current Date::" + date);

        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -2);
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -19);
        date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println("Birthdate ::" + date);

    }
}
```

Hope this solution works.