# Adding Period to startDate doesn't produce endDate

Tags: kotlin, java-time, localdate, period, date-difference

I have two `LocalDate`s declared as following:

```
val startDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 10, 31)  // 2019-10-31
val endDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 9, 30)     // 2019-09-30
```

Then I calculate the period between them using `Period.between` function:

```
val period = Period.between(startDate, endDate) // P-1M-1D
```

Here the period has the negative amount of months and days, which is expected given that `endDate` is earlier than `startDate`.

However when I add that `period` back to the `startDate`, the result I'm getting is not the `endDate`, but the date one day earlier:

```
val endDate1 = startDate.plus(period)  // 2019-09-29
```

So the question is, why doesn't the invariant

`startDate.plus(Period.between(startDate, endDate)) == endDate`

hold for these two dates?

Is it `Period.between` who returns an incorrect period, or `LocalDate.plus` who adds it incorrectly?

Comment: Note that this question looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41945704, however it's not entirely the same. 
I understand that after adding period and subtracting it back (`date.plus(period).minus(period)`) the result is not always the same date. 
This question is more about `Period.between` function's invariants.

Comment: That is how `java.time`-calendar arithmetic works. Basically adding and removing are not conversible to each other, especially not if the day-of-month of one or both dates is bigger than 28. See also the class documentation of [AbstractDuration](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/engine/AbstractDuration.html) in my time lib Time4J for more mathematical background...

Comment: @MenoHochschild The `AbstractDuration` docs are stating that the invariance `t1.plus(t1.until(t2)).equals(t2) == true` should hold, and I'm asking why it's not the case with `java.time` here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look how `plus` is implemented for `LocalDate`

```
@Override
public LocalDate plus(TemporalAmount amountToAdd) {
    if (amountToAdd instanceof Period) {
        Period periodToAdd = (Period) amountToAdd;
        return plusMonths(periodToAdd.toTotalMonths()).plusDays(periodToAdd.getDays());
    }
    ...
}
```

you'll see `plusMonths(...)` and `plusDays(...)` there.

`plusMonths` handles cases when one month has 31 days, and the other has 30. So the following code will print `2019-09-30` instead of non-existent `2019-09-31`

```
println(startDate.plusMonths(period.months.toLong()))
```

After that, subtracting one day results in `2019-09-29`. This is the correct result, since `2019-09-29` and `2019-10-31` are 1 month 1 day apart

The `Period.between` calculation is weird and in this case boils down to

```
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.from(endDateExclusive);
    long totalMonths = end.getProlepticMonth() - this.getProlepticMonth();
    int days = end.day - this.day;
    long years = totalMonths / 12;
    int months = (int) (totalMonths % 12);  // safe
    return Period.of(Math.toIntExact(years), months, days);
```

where `getProlepticMonth` is total number of months from 00-00-00. In this case, it's 1 month and 1 day.

From my understanding, it's a bug in a `Period.between` and `LocalDate#plus` for negative periods interaction, since the following code has the same meaning

```
val startDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 10, 31)
val endDate = LocalDate.of(2019, 9, 30)
val period = Period.between(endDate, startDate)

println(endDate.plus(period))
```

but it prints the correct `2019-10-31`.

The problem is that `LocalDate#plusMonths` normalises date to be always "correct". In the following code, you can see that after subtracting 1 month from `2019-10-31` the result is `2019-09-31` that is then normalised to `2019-10-30`

```
public LocalDate plusMonths(long monthsToAdd) {
    ...
    return resolvePreviousValid(newYear, newMonth, day);
}

private static LocalDate resolvePreviousValid(int year, int month, int day) {
    switch (month) {
        ...
        case 9:
        case 11:
            day = Math.min(day, 30);
            break;
    }
    return new LocalDate(year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you are simply out of luck. The invariant that you have invented sounds reasonable, but doesn’t hold in java.time.

It seems that the `between` method just subtracts the month numbers and the days of month and since the results have the same sign, is content with this result. I think I agree that probably a better decision could have been taken here, but as @Meno Hochschild has correctly stated, math involving the 29, 30 or 31 of months can hardly be clearcut, and I dare not suggest what the better rule would have been.

I bet they are not going to change it now. Not even if you file a bug report (which you can always try). Too much code is already relying on how it’s been working for more than five and a half years.

Adding `P-1M-1D` back into the start date works the way I would have expected. Subtracting 1 month from (really adding –1 month to) October 31 yeilds September 30, and subtracting 1 day yields September 29. Again, it’s not clear-cut, you could argue in favour of September 30 instead.

Answer (score 3):

Analyzing your expectation (in pseudo code)

```
startDate.plus(Period.between(startDate, endDate)) == endDate
```

we have to discuss several topics:

- how to handle separate units like months or days?
- how is the addition of a duration (or "period") defined?
- how to determine the temporal distance (duration) between two dates?
- how is the subtraction of a duration (or "period") defined?

**Let's first look at the units.** Days are no problem because they are the smallest possible calendar unit and every calendar date differs by any other date in full integers of days. So we always have in pseudo code equal if positive or negative:

```
startDate.plus(ChronoUnit.Days.between(startDate, endDate)) == endDate
```

Months however are tricky because the gregorian calendar defines calendar months with different lengths. So the situation can arise that the addition of any integer of months to a date can cause an invalid date:

[2019-08-31] + P1M = [2019-09-31]

The decision of `java.time` to reduce the end date to a valid one - here [2019-09-30] - is reasonable and corresponds to the expectations of most users because the final date still preserves the calculated month. However, this **addition including an end-of-month-correction is NOT reversible**, see the reverted operation called subtraction:

[2019-09-30] - P1M = [2019-08-30]

The result is also reasonable because a) the basic rule of month addition is to keep the day-of-month as much as possible and b) [2019-08-30] + P1M = [2019-09-30].

**What is the addition of a duration (period) exactly?**

In `java.time`, a `Period` is a composition of items consisting of years, months and days with any integer partial amounts. So the addition of a `Period` can be resolved to the addition of the partial amounts to the starting date. Since years are always convertible to 12-multiples of months, we can first combine years and months and then add the total in one step in order to avoid strange side effects in leap years. The days can be added in the last step. A reasonable design as done in `java.time`.

**How to determine the right `Period` between two dates?**

Let's first discuss the case when the duration is positive, meaning the starting date is before the ending date. Then we can always define the duration by first determining the difference in months and then in days. This order is important to achieve a month component because otherwise every duration between two dates would only consist of days. Using your example dates:

[2019-09-30] + P1M1D = [2019-10-31]

Technically, the starting date is first moved forward by the calculated difference in months between start and end. Then the day delta as difference between the moved start date and the end date is added to the moved start date. This way we can calculate the duration as P1M1D in the example. So far so reasonable.

**How to subtract a duration?**

Most interesting point in the previous addition example is, there is by accident NO end-of-month-correction. Nevertheless `java.time` fails to do the reverse subtraction.
It first subtracts the months and then the days:

[2019-10-31] - P1M1D = [2019-09-29]

If `java.time` had instead tried to reverse the steps in the addition before then **the natural choice would have been to first subtract the days and then the months**. With this changed order, we would get [2019-09-30]. The changed order in the subtraction would help as long as there was no end-of-month-correction in the corresponding addition step. This is especially true if the day-of-month of any starting or ending date is not bigger than 28 (the minimum possible month length). Unfortunately `java.time` has defined another design for the subtraction of `Period` which leads to less consistent results.

**Is the addition of a duration reversible in the subtraction?**

First we have to understand that the suggested changed order in the subtraction of a duration from a given calendar date does not guarantee the reversibility of the addition. Counter example which has an end-of-month-correction in the addition:

```
[2011-03-31] + P3M1D = [2011-06-30] + P1D = [2011-07-01] (ok)
[2011-07-01] - P3M1D = [2011-06-30] - P3M = [2011-03-30] :-(
```

Changing the order is not bad because it yields more consistent results. But
how to cure the remaining deficiencies? The only way left is to change the calculation of the duration, too. Instead of using P3M1D, we can see that the duration P2M31D will work in both directions:

```
[2011-03-31] + P2M31D = [2011-05-31] + P31D = [2011-07-01] (ok)
[2011-07-01] - P2M31D = [2011-05-31] - P2M = [2011-03-31] (ok)
```

So the idea is to change the normalization of the computed duration. This can be done by looking if the addition of the computed month delta is reversible in a subtraction step - i.e. avoids the need for an end-of-month-correction. `java.time` does unfortunately not offer such a solution. It is not a bug, but can be considered as a design limitation.

**Alternatives?**

I have enhanced my time library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) by reversible metrics which deploy the ideas given above. See following example:

```
    PlainDate d1 = PlainDate.of(2011, 3, 31);
    PlainDate d2 = PlainDate.of(2011, 7, 1);

    TimeMetric<CalendarUnit, Duration<CalendarUnit>> metric =
        Duration.inYearsMonthsDays().reversible();
    Duration<CalendarUnit> duration =
        metric.between(d1, d2); // P2M31D
    Duration<CalendarUnit> invDur =
        metric.between(d2, d1); // -P2M31D

    assertThat(d1.plus(duration), is(d2)); // first invariance
    assertThat(invDur, is(duration.inverse())); // second invariance
    assertThat(d2.minus(duration), is(d1)); // third invariance
```